# Sumifs with logical OR using cell references

Tags: excel-formula

I am using sumifs with `OR` as shown below:

`=SUM(SUMIF(B:B,{"Apples","Oranges"},C:C))`

The above works fine but instead of `Apples` and `Oranges` I want to use the cell reference that contains this text as shown below:

`=SUM(SUMIF(B:B,{D4,D5},C:C))`

Apparently "There's a problem with this formula". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT to avoid the need for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and just put the full range reference without the `{}`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(B:B,D4:D5,C:C))
```

If the range is not consequitive then you will need to change the formula to something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(B:B,CHOOSE({1,2},D4,D7),C:C))
```